# Percentages in css using meteor?

Tags: css, meteor

I'm just started making my first Meteor app and I wanted my div to to be the same height as the page, so logically I set the height to 100%. It didn't work. Then I set the width to 100%. That also didn't work. Is there a mistake in my code? Or maybe does Meteor parse css weirdly?

```
<head>
  <title>Facer</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="home">
  <div id="face">
    <img id="faceimg" src="http://raritea.com/raritea/images/logo.svg"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#face {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
Router.map(function(){
     this.route('home', {path: '/'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Or maybe does Meteor parse css weirdly?* **No**, meteor works exactly like other web framework.

Try with this css.

```
#face {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also in order to use iron:route and get off the `<body>` tag i recommend you to use the `layout template`, like this.

```
<template name="layout">
 {{> yield}}
</template>

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'layout',
})
```

The `{{> yield}}` helper will take care of us to render the template home

Here is the [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/LWiZk6og5JRNriBFN/Leaderboard) with the div full `width/height` on the screen.

**Tutorial iron:router**

Check the [Manuel Schoebel iron router tutorial](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) is a good start point

Comment: the absolute tell the div #face to take the place of his antecetor (in this case the body tag), also if this help you please check the answer to "accepted" (checkmark under this post, on the left I think it's right below the arrows) or check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to know how to do it

Comment: upvote his question to help him get enough to upvote your answer also :)